# Application access server load

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have developed an application in PHP + JavaScript. I'm using MySQL as database support. Every account for this app will come with a subdomain... so the client Stardust would have `stardust.mysite.com`. I want to put the application files in a folder outside `public_html` and link every account from every subdomain created to this files folder through a config file that would stay in each subdomain. Just for specifying the database Infos. My questions are: Would I have more server load if I put every customer to access files from the same folder than I would have if I put the files in every subdomain, separately for every client? Would 500 customers access the files at the same time all from one location be the same with 500 customers accessing files separately from its own folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system will cache files, so having 500 copies means a lot more caching and a lot more disk IO than one copy. You may want to simply have a "master" application that understands subdomains (i.e. user1 is associated with subdomain1) and use apache redirects/etc to send all the requests to the master application/etc.